# need assistance creating sql query with two IN statements

Tags: php, mysql

I need a query that has two `IN()` statements inside it.

Of course the following is totally wrong, but it's sort of what I'm looking for:

```
<?php
$query = mysql_query("SELECT 1.field1, 1.field3, M.field2 FROM table 1, table2 2 WHERE 1.field1=2.field2 and 1.field3 IN (0,1)AND 1.field2 IN (5,2)) or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: numbers as table aliases? That sounds risky. Plus, no end quote symbol

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, or purely a query problem?

Comment: I would recommend numbers as aliases, also I would strongly recommend protecting yourself from sql injection. Have a look at prepared statements. 3rd example down uses IN http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm

Comment: the numbers are just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT A.field1,
           A.field3,
           A.field2
    FROM   table A,
           table2 B
    WHERE  A.field1=B.field2
           AND A.field3 IN (0,1)
           AND A.field2 IN (5,2)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Should work. It's worth noting that you're using old-style join syntax (ANSI-89) the newer standard ANSI-92 has been out for 2 decades and you should really start using it...

```
$query = mysql_query("
    SELECT A.field1,
           A.field3,
           A.field2
    FROM   table A
           INNER JOIN table2 B
               ON A.field1=B.field2
    WHERE  A.field3 IN (0,1)
           AND A.field2 IN (5,2)") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: The MySQL documentation examples are still catching up.

Comment: FWIW, you can also do `and (A.field3 , A.field2) in ( (0,5), (1,2) )` but not sure if that's what you want here.

Comment: @gillyspy Thanks for the tip, I wasn't aware of that syntax.